# Is there any way to acess specific instances of a class in the class iteslf

Tags: python, class

Is there any way of acessing instaces of classes and the variables in them from inside the class without specfically calling the name of the instance?

```
class test:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    @staticmethod
    def isTen():
        if(x.x == 10 or y.x == 10):
            return True
        else:
            return False
x = test(1)
y = test(10)
```

I want to create a static function inside the class that checks if there is an instance with an x variable that has the value 10. Is there any way to do this without hardcoding the names of the instance into the function so that it's scaleable up to work with more instance variables and values?

Comment: can you clarify what your end goal is?  There are many ways to do this, some better and some worse

Comment: also: `staticmethods` by definition don't directly access class/instance attributes.  Maybe you mean `classmethod`?

Comment: classes have no access to all instances it creates. If you want to do that, you have to write the code to keep track of those instances

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not proper programming. You need a `TestCollection` class that allocates and keeps track of all the `Test` instances. The `Test` instances just worry about themselves, They don't have any idea there even ARE other instances.

Just consider how delicate your current design is.  What if you decided to move your `class Test` to another file?  You can't have it assuming the names of global variables.